# Looking for a memory-efficient way of deleting rows from a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In my long-running process, I call the following statement to purge rows from a dataframe:

```
df = df.iloc[purge_threshold:]
```

To my understanding (hopefully, I am wrong), the above statement creates and returns a duplicate clone of the selected rows in a new instance of a dataframe. The original instance of the dataframe is left unreferenced for garbage collection. During long-running process scenarios, the above statement is awfully memory inefficient.

Is there any way to delete the rows from the same instance of a dataframe like how we delete elements from a list?

Comment: I believe it is not possible as the memory for a dataframe object must be in a continuous memory buffer. Dropped rows will create holds which violate its functions.